# What is the behaviour of calling pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_mutex_unlock with NULL?

Tags: c, pthreads

What is the behaviour of calling pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_mutex_unlock with NULL as an argument ?

Comment: A kernel error if you are lucky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_mutex_lock.3p.html). It clearly states:

> If mutex does not refer to an initialized mutex object, the
> behavior of pthread_mutex_lock(), pthread_mutex_trylock(), and
> pthread_mutex_unlock() is undefined.

If you are experienced with C you probably know what that means: **Don't do it!**